# R function to find rank of a value in a sorted vector

Tags: r, vector, rank

I'd like to find the rank of a value in a sorted vector, i.e., given a sorted (increasing) vector and a value, find the index of the value in the vector if it is present (or the mean of indices if more than once), or the index of the greatest element less than the value, if it is not present, but within the range of the vector, or something reasonable if the value is outside the range of the vector altogether.

Let's say `xx` is the vector and `x` is the value. `mean(which(xx == x))` covers the value-present case, and `max(which(xx < x))` covers the value-not-present-and-in-range case. 1 and length(xx) are probably reasonable outputs for the not-in-range case.

So I could do that, but I'd like to avoid creating a Boolean vector the size of `xx`, and also there are just enough wrinkles that I'd prefer to call a built-in or library function instead of rolling my own. Perhaps there is something simple which I've overlooked.

Here's an example. The first value, 7, is present in the vector. The second, 7.3, is not present. I'd like to get the outputs 82.5 and 86, respectively.

```
> sort (floor (runif (100) * 10)) -> xx
> xx
  [1] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2
 [38] 2 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 6 6 6 6
 [75] 6 6 6 6 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 8 8 8 8 8 8 8 8 8 8 8 9 9 9
> mean (which (xx == 7))
[1] 82.5
> max (which (xx <= 7.3))
[1] 86
```

EDIT: with hints from akrun, I've come up with the following. Note that when there are duplicates, make use of the fact that `match` returns the least index and `findInterval` returns the greatest.

```
# assume xx is sorted already
mean.rank.in <- function (xx, x) { 
    findInterval (x, xx) -> i 
    if (i == 0) 0
    else
        if (xx[[i]] == x)
            # account for duplicates here:
            # findInterval returned greatest index, call match to find least
            (match(x, xx) + i)/2
        else i
}
```

Here are some checks:

```
xx <- c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3,
3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5,
5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7,
7, 7, 7, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 9, 9, 9)
mean.rank.in (xx, 7) == 82.5 # expect TRUE
mean.rank.in (xx, 7.3) == 86 # expect TRUE
sapply (xx, function (x) mean.rank.in (xx, x)) # looks right
sum (sapply (xx, function (x) mean.rank.in (xx, x))) == 5050 # expect TRUE
yy <- sort (runif (100))
all (sapply (yy, function (y) mean.rank.in (yy, y)) == 1:100) # expect TRUE
dyy <- min (yy[2:100] - yy[1:99])
yy1 <- yy + dyy/2
all (sapply (yy1, function (y) mean.rank.in (yy1, y)) == 1:100) # expect TRUE
mean.rank.in (yy, yy[[1]] - 1) == 0 # expect TRUE
mean.rank.in (yy, yy[[100]] + 1) == 100 # expect TRUE
```

Comment: @akrun I've added an example.

Answer (score 1):

Here is one option with `rank`

```
rank(xx)[match(7, xx)]
#[1] 82.5
```

and with `findInterval`

```
findInterval(7.3, xx)
#[1] 86
```

#### data

```
xx <- c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 
3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5, 
5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 
7, 7, 7, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 9, 9, 9)
```

Comment: Thanks for the hints. I've used that to come up with a solution which I've pasted into the question.

Comment: @RobertDodier Yes, there is an issue with duplicate indexing